# Jenkins Active Choices Plugin input text box don't return anything. Why?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

This is my actual configuration

[image: Domain Param Configuration]

[image: Jenkins Job]

When I type the desired domain there is nothing in domain's variable. Any idea what's going on? I'm totally newbie with groovy script.

Thanks.

BTW, my little and totally useless groovy script:

```
if (Environment.equals("pro")){
  inputBox="<input type='text'>"
  return inputBox
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So I was struggling with the same thing just now and came upon this question so might as well post the solution that worked for me :)

My paramater name in jenkins is "Partner"

My groovy script:

```
inputBox = "<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
return inputBox
```

It seems that the value inputed is stored in a variable that has the paramater name;
Soo... if you wana use the Value inputed just use the variable like this `${Partner}` or `%Partner%` (depending on where you want to use it);

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: It helped me. However, it is adding comma (,) to the value entered at the end.

Comment: Had same issue and got the value twice. Is there a solution for this? If I enter "hello" in textbox, the result would be:  "echo hello,
                                                hello"

Comment: got the answer here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40179

Answer (score 1):

i found value should is being saved when only we pass name='value' attribute to build as parameter as per doc .

Answer (score 0):

How are you evaluating that there is no value passed on from the Domain input box? It looks like the problem is that you aren't assigning a name attribute to your input box, thus I'm not sure how you would retrieve the value. Try `<input name='domain' type='text'/>` and then see if the `domain` variable has a value.

I see that the Active Choice Plugin also has a "Choice Type" of input box, but I'm not sure if that fits what you are trying to do.